# New dimmer switch and lights misbehaving - 2 cycles through one knob turn

Tags: dimmer-switch

I've recently installed a dimmer light switch in place of a standard light switch and have run into an odd output.

Through one rotation of the dimmer knob, the lights go through the dimming cycle twice - see [linked movie](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YKOK5Ng1hYMgB8v-wypnkuy47FKCdhZS)

The switch is suited for LED lights, trailing, and rated 10-450W - the lights are LED dimmable at 4W each (24W total).

Googling the issue for hours hasn't really gotten me any closer to a reason/answer, and it all seems to be wired up fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks! Sam

Comment: What make and model are the lamps and dimmer involved in this?

Comment: If you stick *one* incandescent bulb in the fixture, does that change anything?

Comment: It sounds like a bad pot. Most are metal film and if bad it could do this , I would return it for an exchange.

Comment: Thanks! The light switch is INOVO, a NZ brand new to the scene - but according to them compliant with Aus/NZ standards.
The bulbs are Baseus A60
Overall, potentially, not a high quality system..

Comment: When I put an 8W LED light in the fixture.. The new LED light flickered for the first 60% while the other dimmable LEDs (5 now) remained off. The dimmable LEDs came on for the last 40% properly.

Comment: Thanks - will get in touch with manufacturer re pot